# how to identify the tag position in image inside a webview?

Tags: android, webview, android-image

Basically my idea is to display some story to user .The story contain title ,Images and the story content .Images and contents are arranged in a mixed manner.I have this content as HTML in back end .Now I will display this using webView in Android.My requirement is,There will be some tagged image in my story ,So i need to display that tags and i wanted to do something when user click on that tagged position

Something like this
[image: Somthing like this]

Comment: Did you get any solution? I need it.